# Xcode won't start after first launch?

Tags: xcode

I recently installed Xcode and after closing out of the first launch (because I realized I had more configuring to do).  I cannot get it to re-launch.  The icon will come up, but no program will show up.  I do not get an error, and I am launching from the /Developer folder (not /Applications).  I have tried re-installing/restarting multiple times to no avail.  I have the latest version, and I am running Snow Leopard (10.6.6).

Comment: thanks Igor, your question saved me xD

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> The icon will come up, but no program will show up.

Are you new to OS X?  It sounds like you are describing the way OS X apps normally start up.  By default, Xcode pops up a window with a list of most recent projects, but you can switch this off.  It doesn't mean that Xcode isn't running, it just means you don't have any Xcode windows open.  You can still select any of the usual menu items to start new projects, open existing projects, etc.

Comment: correct - just to add - the xCode icon starts jumping to indicate xCode is being launched. When the launch is complete, you don't see an IDE - just the menu bar at the top changes - you will the text next to the apple icon on the left side changes to "XCode" - this is quite counter intuitive for a non-mac user

Comment: I'm not new and I'm running into the issue as well. It stops bouncing as apps do when they launch, but when it stops it doesn't have the dot under it indicating it is open. My menu bar doesn't change. It isn't open in any windows. I can still force quit from the force quit menu. I run into this every time I download a new version. It seems like evenutally I get something that says verifying app or the window that loads the new command line tools then it works. But I don't know how to get there and I just get stuck.

Answer (score 20):

The answer to this problem is I believe easily sorted. Once you open X code and all you get is the menu bar at the top, go to Window, Welcome to x Code, then check the box bottom left hand corner of that screen 'Show this window when Xcode launches'

Job done ! Now every time you hit the Xcode icon where ever it is the welcome screen will open and from there you can proceed into the program.

Answer (score 10):

Probably not your problem, but I had issues starting xcode with it trying to load up the last project I was working on. It would just hang and I had to force quit it.

In the end I deleted these directories:

project.xcworkspace/
xcuserdata/

and next time I tried to restart xcode it started fine.

Comment: I found a bunch of these under "~/Library/Autosave Information" and this also solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

Please go project folder and right click ."xcworkspace" and open "show package contents"-> xcuserdata and delete user folder and then relaunch.

Comment: This is the correct answer for this problem.Solved it,thank you @Chaturka

Answer (score 2):

In my case I launched XCode 6 (beta 7) on my MacBook Pro Mid 2010, and I had to wait for ~10minutes for anything to happen. I didn't see icon in dock, or even menu bar - just a reference in Force Quit Applications menu. After those 10 minutes classic alert with "You have downloaded Xcode from internet..." title appeared and then i had to wait another 5 minutes for another progress (installation of additional components).In overall it took Xcode 6 ~25 minutes to start.

So... Patience! :)

Comment: This was my answer also. I opened it.. It kept bouncing for about 10 minutes. Finally it prompt "This was opened from the internet". After I said "Open" it bounced for another 5 minutes. It finally ended after the terms and conditions "Agree" and installed additional components.